# React Native Firebase only works on iOS

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm fairly new to React Native so I've been following the "The Complete React Native and Redux Course" by Stephen Grider. On section 9, lecture 59 he installs Firebase using npm with "npm install --save firebase", and so did I, however this only works for iOS for me. Whenever I run the app on an Android simulator I get this error saying `Objects are not valid as a React child`.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWOU1.png)

Edit: I'll try to explain this problem better as per advice from akraf. The only thing I need to do to recreate this Error is create a React Native project. Then install Firebase through npm to the project directory. Once I add the line "import firebase from 'firebase';" to the App.js file, the error occurs. Nothing else, just the import causes the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It might help people which can potentially help if you show more in detail how you got to this screen shot. For example try to write the simplest possible app which shows this problem and add the the Java code to the question. You can [edit] your question to that effect. Also your screenshot is not readable.

Comment: @akraf Thank you very much for your comment. I tried to explain the situation a bit better and fixed the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install the version 5.0.2. Use this command as administrator:

```
npm install --save firebase@5.0.2
```

As far as i see, the current version (5.0.4) is buggy!

Comment: Tried to run that command but all I got was a bunch of errors during the installation. I am on MacOS, don't know if that affects anything.

Comment: @Astherae first, try to uninstall the previous version, npm uninstall --save firebase the use my cmd - or create the project from scratch and then use my cmd!

Comment: I did create a new project when I tried your command, and it didn't work. I also ran it as admin.

Comment: @Astherae what are errors you get? update your post and add them so i can check

Comment: Alright I figured it out. This time I ran this command:
npm install firebase@5.0.3 --save --save-exact
And it worked, thank you very much for your help, this was driving me insane.

Comment: @Astherae that drove me insane before :)) glad for u, yw :D